# Image of the reduction map $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}) \to \operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be prime, and suppose that a matrix $A \in \operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})$ has $\det A \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$. Is it necessarily the case that there exists some matrix $\tilde{A} \in \operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\tilde{A} \equiv A \pmod{p^2}$?

We have a natural reduction map $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}) \to \operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})$, and clearly every matrix in the image of this map has determinant $1 \in \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$. So my question is basically whether that necessary condition is also sufficient to lie in the image of the map.

Using Python, I have brute-forced the cases $(n,p) = (2,3), (2,5)$, and it does hold in those situations. More generally, I have tried to prove the result in general for $n=2$, but without much success.

Comment: Yes, it suffices to prove that the image contains the permutation matrices and $GL_2$ ie. $\pmatrix{*&\\&*}$ and $\pmatrix{1&*\\&1}$

Comment: @user8675309 ah yes you're right - I've edited the question

Comment: @reuns are you just talking about the $n=2$ case?

Comment: No ${}{}{}{}{}$